# How do I group by count of a field in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb

I have some data in InfluxDB that is connected events for certain TCP connections. So the measurement is connection_events with tags being: mac_address of connecting system, and some other metadata. The value is just connected=true|false

What I want to do is something like this:

```
select count(mac_address), mac_address 
from connection_events 
where count(mac_address) > X 
group by mac_address
```

In other words, I want to see results like:

> 28,ABCD
>
> 14,EFGH
>
> 3,XYZQ

However, InfluxDB doesn't like this kind of query. I can't figure out how to parse through the dataset of connection events and aggregate them by mac address.

Comment: As of influxdb 1.2 there are subqueries but you are not allowed to use the `mac_address` value in the select so you still cannot have this kind of results. See: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/data_exploration/#subqueries

Answer (score 7):

Functions in InfluxQL are not valid outside the `SELECT` clause, and there are as yet no subqueries or a `HAVING` clause.

However, you can accomplish what you need by using [Continuous Queries](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.11/query_language/continuous_queries/)

Use a CQ to calculate the `count(mac_address)` and store that in a new measurement `foo`. `CREATE CQ... SELECT COUNT(mac_address) AS count INTO foo FROM connection_events GROUP BY time(5m), *` Then for your graph you can query `select count from foo where count > X group by mac_address`.

Comment: so, you're saying that unless we store the aggregates into a new measurement, we can't run aggregate queries grouping by a tag? that's a BIG DISAPPOINTMENT!