# How to create a percentage / ratio column in Grafana / InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have the data about the errors written to InfluxDB (example is simplified).

```
 time   | error   | some_unique_data
--------|---------|--------------------
 <time> | hello 1 | some unique data...
 <time> | hello 2 | some unique data...
 <time> | hello 2 | some unique data...
 <time> | hello 3 | some unique data...
```

I can write the following query to see the sorted list of the most frequent errors in Grafana:

```
SELECT COUNT("some_unique_data") FROM "my_measument" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY error
```

which gives:

```
| error   | count
|---------|-------
| hello 2 | 2
| hello 1 | 1
| hello 3 | 1
```

What I am missing is the column that would show me the impact of each error like this:

```
| error   | count | impact
|---------|----------------
| hello 2 | 2     | 50%
| hello 1 | 1     | 25%
| hello 3 | 1     | 25%
```

What should I add to my query to get this `impact` field working?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209516/how-do-i-group-by-count-of-a-field-in-influxdb), but unfortunately it doesn't solve your issue.

In your example:

```
| error   | count
|---------|-------
| hello 2 | 2
| hello 1 | 1
| hello 3 | 1
```

you've used `GROUP BY "error"` to get the count of each `error`, so once you did this you don't have access to the full count anymore, so you must do it before `GROUP BY`.

### You **can't** do:

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) AS full_count, "some_unique_data" FROM "my_measument" WHERE $timeFilter
> ```

in order to get the full number of records because you **can't** use `SELECT COUNT(), "field_name" FROM ...`

So, getting the full count before doing `GROUP BY` isn't possible.

### Well, let's try something else:

```
SELECT "fields_count" / SUM("fields_count") AS not_able_to_use_SUM_with_field , "error" FROM ( 
    SELECT COUNT("some_unique_data") AS fields_count AS fields_sum FROM "my_measument" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "error"
)
```

This previous query isn't working apparently. Then what to do?

Sorry, **You can do Nothing :/**

Here is another [link to the documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/functions).

Comment:  you made my day